# GWT: 2.6 -> 2.8 System.getProperty("line.separator") not supported anymore

Tags: java, gwt

I'm updating my [libgdx](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) game to use [GWT](http://www.gwtproject.org/) 2.8 instead of 2.6. I'm however running into the issue that the compiler doesn't accept my few calls to System.getProperty("line.separator"):

```
[ERROR] Errors in 'com/hgames/core/dm/grid/TextMapParser.java'
  [ERROR] Line 138: Property 'line.separator' is not defined.
```

I'm puzzled, because it was accepted before and I could not find information regarding emulation of System's properties. I'm building with gradle and specifying gwt's version with "gwtVersion='2.8.0'".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a new feature since 2.8.0-beta1 (http://www.gwtproject.org/release-notes.html#Release_Notes_2_8_0_BETA1). You can use System.getProperty to get user defined properties either in the gwt.xml or using command line (-setProperty).

#### Using command line:

In your module

```
<define-configuration-property name="project.version" is-multi-valued="false"/>
```

In your gwt compiler/devmode command line

```
-setProperty project.version=1.2.3
```

Example https://github.com/ibaca/gwt-dagger2-coffee

#### Using module only:

In your module

```
<define-configuration-property name="someConfigurationProperty" is-multi-valued='false'/>
<set-configuration-property name="someConfigurationProperty" value="conf"/>
```

Example https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/blob/a90832fec9a56f4cb83ed009c7048e0a8d196fe8/user/test/com/google/gwt/emultest/java/lang/SystemTest.java#L320

Comment: That said, I don't understand how that can cause a regression, as System.getProperty shouldn't have worked with earlier versions.

Comment: Yep I thought the same... maybe gdx has super-sourced getProperty... uhm.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/commit/7ed40698018bb789916ffea6ca8b2a4f64961f92#diff-04e57b8ce51ea73dda5e3f402518370f